# Append Div to area shape id with jquery

Tags: jquery, append, imagemap

Is this possible to append a div "mydiv" to an area shape id like below:

```
<area id="one" shape="rect" coords="335,239,376,282" href="#" />
```

Comment: Why don't you try it out and report back ??

Answer (score 2):

As `area` is a self closing element, it can't hold other elements.
If you append a div to an area element, most browser will try and fix your error by adding a closing `</area>` tag, and actually add the div inside, but it won't do much good, as the area tag only defines a certain space/area in an image, and a div has no place in an image, and the content won't be visible ?

In other words, **no** you can't do that!

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NRNBB/)

Comment: append won't include the element. It will just sit it nicely under it. Unless i misread the OP's desired outcome?

Comment: @JamieHutber - In Chrome it closes the area tag and appends the DIV, but the content is not visible. I added a fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Adeneo, I am looking to achieve having a map of the U.S. and when the user rollovers over the area shape that particular div that is attached would appear. How would go you go about achieving this?

Comment: You can not style or change the apperance of an area tag, all you can do is attach hover/mouse events to it, so when hovering the area, you change the image src etc. That's how maps like that are made.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#one').append('<div id="mydiv">Something in here</div>");
```

I believe something like this will do the trick.